# How to get the @ syntax to work in asp.net page

Tags: asp.net

I've started the w3 asp.net tutorial and I've fallen at the first hurdle.

The first example in the tutorial is:

```
<html>
<body>
     <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1>
     <p>The time is @DateTime.Now</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This outputs @DateTime.Now as @DateTime.Now

If I change the code to:

```
<html>
<body>
     <h1>Hello Web Pages</h1>
     <p>The time is <%= DateTime.Now %></p>
</body>
</html>
```

This outputs the date and time.

I'm running IIS 10 on windows 10.  I'm not using VS or VS Code, just a text editor so I can concentrate on the language and not get bogged down by the IDE.

Is there some IIS setting I need to enable to make the @syntax work or is there something I need to install?  Is there something that needs to go into the web config file?

Completely new to ASP.NET - can someone help me out here please.

Comment: `just a text editor` - how are you compiling? Is this the raw file you upload to IIS?

Comment: yes - just the raw file.  JIT compile I assume

Comment: The `@` is Razor syntax (.cshtml), the `<%=` is webforms (.aspx) - there is a variety of web technologies in .Net with lots of differences

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5900066/11683? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17309973/11683?

Comment: Where in web.config should `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />` be put?  Am getting internal server error.  Have tried it in various places.

Comment: `<configuration><appSettings>`

Comment: Still getting error, but with this message now: `The configuration section 'configuration' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration `

Comment: Gave up in the end and used Visual Studio.  Still had to set some things up in IIS.